# Paracompactness of Quotient by Group Action

Tags: gn.general-topology, differential-topology, paracompactness

Suppose $X$ is a metric space with a free group action by a topological group $G$, which is also a metric space, such that $\pi\colon X \to X/G$ is a fiber bundle.

Does the quotient inherit the paracompactness of $X$? If this is not true in general I'm interested in the case, where $X$ is the space of embeddings of a closed surface $\Sigma$ into some closed manifold $M$ with the $C^k$ topology on which $ \text{Diff}(\Sigma)$ acts by precomposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k=\infty$ this is well-known: See 44.1 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf), or 13.14 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf), or  [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/mf-smo-3.pdf) since the base of the principal fiber bundle is a smooth infinite dimensional manifold which is modeled on nuclear Frechet spaces, thus it is smoothly paracompact (there exist smooth partitions of unity). The modelling spaces are spaces of smooth sections of the normal bundle of $f(\Sigma)$ for a fixed embedding $f$.

If $k$ is finite, one has to adapt the proof: Use only smooth $C^\infty$ embeddings as bases for the trivializing charts, then the construction of the normal bundle does not loose differentiability, so one can still consider the space of $C^k$ sections of the normal bundle. Attention: the action of the group of $C^k$-diffeomorphisms (which is only a topological group: $k\ge 1$) is only continuous.  The quotient is still a smooth manifold modelled on Banach spaces: Reading carefully through the proof one notices, that one can find explicit chart changes involving only smooth embeddings and smooth diffeomorphisms which act from the right, thus smoothly even on $C^k$ embeddings.  Also smooth local fiber respecting diffeomorphisms act smoothly on on spaces of $C^k$-sections.

But the modelling Banach spaces of $C^k$-sections do not admit smooth partitions of unity. So the quotient space is only paracompact (since the base is second countable). See section 16 of   [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf) for this.

Comment: I'm trying to find the reference in "The convenient setting for global Analysis", where it is mentioned that locally nuclear Frechet space implies paracompact. Could you maybe help me out once more?

Comment: @ThorbenK: 42.3 and the proof used there.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm a little bit slow on this but I can't patch all of this together. Proposition 42.3 says that $C^\infty(\Sigma,M)$ is metrizable, which of course also applies to the open subset $\text{Emb}(\Sigma,M)$ but how do you get from this to the fact that the base space of the described principal bundle is paracompact? Using 42.3 and the corollary in 27.4 I still need that the base space is Linderlöf.

Comment: The base is Lindeloef, since it is the continuous image of Emb, which is Lindeloef, being second countable metrizable.

Comment: @PeterMichor : I'm sorry to reopen an old comment thread, but I was also trying to follow through the reasoning, and I have a question about the corollary in section 27.4 of your book, which is used in the proof that $\mathrm{Emb}(L,M)/\mathrm{Diff}(L)$ is paracompact for finite-dimensional smooth manifolds $L$, $M$ with $L$ compact. If I understand correctly, the corollary says, roughly (omitting the word "smoothly" for brevity), that Hausdorff plus Lindelöf plus locally regular implies paracompact.

Comment: The proof says that this follows from Theorem 16.10. But this theorem says (again omitting the word "smoothly") that Lindelöf plus regular implies paracompact, so it appears to assume stronger hypotheses. Moreover, I have [come across](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2002&task=show_msg&msg=0115.0003) a counterexample to the non-smooth version of the statement of the corollary in 27.4.

Comment: So this corollary seems to be a special phenomenon of the smooth setting. How does it follow from Theorem 16.10? I can't quite see the connection at the moment. For example, does smoothly Hausdorff plus locally smoothly regular imply smoothly regular? (The non-smooth version of this statement is false.) Apologies for the very long comment(s)!

Comment: The definition of smoothly regular in "The Convenient Setting for Global Analysis" is that for every neighborhood of a point $x$ there exists a smooth function such that $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus 0)$ is contained in that neighborhood and $f(x)=1$ (See the definition right before Proposition 14.2). Therefore locally smoothly regular and smoothly regular are the same.

Comment: Thanks! So the correct non-smooth analogue to have in mind is not regularity, as I was saying, but *functional* regularity. But I don't see how to prove your statement that locally smoothly regular and smoothly regular are the same. Suppose $X$ is locally smoothly regular, so each point has a neighbourhood basis of smoothly regular subsets. Given $x\in X$ and an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, we may find a smaller neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ that is smoothly regular. But any function we obtain from smooth regularity of $V$ will be defined only on $V$, so I don't see how to proceed from here...?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I was a bit fast on that one and thought that you could just extend them, but this is a priori not clear. Maybe Peter Michor can shed some light onto this.

Comment: @MartinPalmer I think the point in the present case is the following: Take a point $x\in X$ then (I hope I'm not running into some Function Analysis issues here) there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, which is diffeomorphic to some topological vector space and which is an honest subset of a neighborhood $U'$, which is also diffeomorphic to a topological vector space. Now for every neighborhood $V$ of $x$ we can find a function $f\colon U'\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus 0)\subset U\cap V$ and such that $f(x)=1$. Then note that $f$ is constantly zero on $U'\setminus U$...

Comment: @MartinPalmer and therefore if $X$ is obtained by gluing $U'$ to $X\setminus U$ via $U \setminus U'$ (which again I hope it is) then we can extend $f$ to all of $X$ via the constant $0$ function.